# Nativescript AutoComplete not visible

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Do any have the latest working solution for Autocomplete?
I tried above steps but nothing is visible on screen

Appreciate your answer and help!

I tried this steps but nothing worked or visible on screen...

The array of items:

```
var item:Array<string> = ['1','2','3','4']
```

and in the HTML of the component:

```
<StackLayout>
    <AutoComplete [items]="item" itemTap="itemTapped($event)"> </AutoComplete>      
</StackLayout>
```

-Regards

Comment: "Above steps"?..

Comment: I tried following code but nothings work or visible on screen..

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So I guess you're using this plugin: https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-autocomplete .. and you're using it with Angular, right? Did you register the `AutoComplete` tag in your code?

Comment: I assume you are using the plugin nativescript-autocomplete, I do not think it is compatible with {N} + Angular as it was last updated 10 months ago. Maybe ask the dev of the plugin for more info.

Comment: For what it is worth the `RadAutoCompleteTextView` is planned to be added to the Angular supported components by the mid of June. You can check it out here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/AutoCompleteTextView/overview

Comment: RadAutoCompleteTextView is Pro version, I want to go with free components.

Comment: Did anyone tried Autocomplete with NativeScript 3.0 Version ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to create something, It's not a plugin, just a piece of code you can include in your project. I tested on tns-android 3.1.1 and tns-core-modules @ 3.1.1. Not
Check it on GitHub https://github.com/mbayi/nativescript-AutoComplete