# Autocompletion in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, xml, autocomplete, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have a SearchBar in XML and I need to make it with autocomplete but without Telerik UI Pro autocomplete because I can't afford it. I tried with the npm nativescript-autocomplete modul but it didn't work and it's with .ts (TypeScript) and Angular but not pure js.

I did some research but nothing. I need it with XML AND pure Javascript, if you have some tips for me, I will appreciate that.

I can take a picture of my code if necessary but its not really interesting.

Comment: Even if its written in TS you should be  able to use it with pure JS as inside node_modules you will have only JS file

Comment: @MarekMaszay Ok, I will developped on this side. I will write you if I found an answer, thanks

Comment: @MarekMaszay Didn't work.. and the npm nativescript-autocomplete display nothing. I think another person on Stackoverflow post this same question about the display but he didn't got answers. I didn't get error and my import is right

Comment: The lastest version of the `nativescript-autocomplete` plugin was developed with {N} `2.1.1` and if your project is targeting anything above 2.x.x it will not work, for example with {N} 3.0.0. The only thing you can do in this case is to hope that the plugin dev upgrades it to support the latest 3.x.x version of NativeScript

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov Oh... Understand now, why its not working... I have the 3.0.2 version. If I used NativeScript version 2. You think it can be good for now? Or it will have some future serious problems?

Comment: @Erased Well you could go back to 2.x.x but that means essentially that all features/improvements from 3.x.x are lost and you wont be able to take advantage unless you migrate to 3.x.x . Depending on your scenarios both approaches can be used but my suggestion is to try to migrate to 3.x.x and if there are plugins that do not support it, either find a different supported plugin or "force" the creator of the plugin to migrate or you migrate it its open source.

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov Yeah, I noted that! Thanks you very much for your support and your cleared explication. See you soon ;)

Comment: @Erased Anytime.

Comment: Check my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169224/nativescript-autocomplete-not-visible/48680463#48680463
I hope this can work for you